# SharePoint 2010 Rolling Three Months Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi i'm trying to develop a three month rolling calendar view by inserting three calendar webparts in a page and also by inserting the below code in a CEWP.

The calendars should roll to  previous or next respectively but clicking on the button 'PrevMonth' and 'NextMonth'.

It seems to be working for just roll but something is wrong. Can someone help me with this ?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(setCal, 1000);

  });

var CurrentDate = new Date();


function setCal() {
  $("#PrevMonth").click(PrevMonth);
  $("#NextMonth").click(NextMonth);

  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth() + 2).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ3');
  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ2');
  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth()).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ1');
}

function PrevMonth() {
  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth() - 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ3');
  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth() - 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ2');
  MoveToDate((CurrentDate.getMonth() - 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ1');
}

function NextMonth() {
  MoveToDate((currentMonth + 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ3');
  MoveToDate((currentMonth + 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ2');
  MoveToDate((currentMonth + 1).toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getDate().toString() + '\u002f' + CurrentDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'WPQ1');
}

<
/script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, after much searching, this works perfectly.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepoint server/sites/page/Scripts/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myPrevFunction() {
        document.getElementById("WPQ3_nav_prev_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ4_nav_prev_img").click();
        document.getElementById("WPQ5_nav_prev_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ6_nav_prev_img").click();
        document.getElementById("WPQ7_nav_prev_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ8_nav_prev_img").click();
    }

    function myNextFunction() {
        document.getElementById("WPQ3_nav_next_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ4_nav_next_img").click();
        document.getElementById("WPQ5_nav_next_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ6_nav_next_img").click();    
        document.getElementById("WPQ7_nav_next_img").click(); 
        document.getElementById("WPQ8_nav_next_img").click();
    }



    </script>
    <input type="button" id="CFCCalPrev" value="Prev" onclick="myPrevFunction()">
    <input type="button" id="CFCCalNext" value="Next" onclick="myNextFunction()">
```